# Accessing help page of topics with a special character in R

Tags: r

The question might be minor, but I wanted to know the standard way of getting to the help page of topics with special characters.

For topics without special characters, `?` is a shortcut for accessing help on a specified topic in `R`. For example, `?help` or `help(help)` displays the help documentation. Similarly, If I do `?%in%` or `help(%in%)`, I'll get:

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in ...

However, I can get to the help page or a page containing information about the topic using any of:

```
1. ?`%in%` or help(`%in%`)
2. ?"%in%" or help("%in%")
3. ?'%in%' or help('%in%')
```

So long as I'm getting the help documentation, I've been using the first one more often than the others. However, I'm still learning how to use the help pages and want to learn the standard practice.

Does it matter if I use any one of the above to access the help page of a topic?

Thank you.

Comment: No. You get redirected to the same page irrespective.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I just want to be sure so an important and existing help page is left out due not using the retrieving instruction.

Comment: Read about `?Quotes`

Comment: @zx8754, thanks and will give it a thorough read. Using `?"%in%"`  lands me to the `match` documentation where `%in%` is defined. I was trying to check whether I'm using the right instruction to get to the help page of `%in%` if it exists by itself so I don't miss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not missing out on any information. You land on the same page irrespective of whatever alternative you chose.

The help pages of some commands are the same. For example, `match` and `%in%` OR `grep` `grepl` , `gsub` and `sub` which might be confusing at times.

Comment: I developed the habit to use `help("%in%")` on Stack Overflow. Two advantages: it is very obvious what this does and it uses a standard function call with standard evaluation (which usually is the safest option). `'` and `"` are of course fully equivalent and you only need to distinguish for nested quotes such as in `help('"')`.